# get Id of long pressed item in onCreateContextMenu method

Tags: android, contextmenu, long-press

My question might be stupid but I just start my adventure with android.

I have two EditText elements in main activity and I want for each of them different context menu. I dont know how can I get Id of long pressed EditText in onCreateContextMenu(params) method so I can make proper context menu for selected EditText.

In all examples I found there is one context menu and no need to know Id of pressed element.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Your OnLongClickListener is passed a view, something like View v. Use v.getId(); to get the id of that view (in this case that should give you the id's of your EditText fields).

Comment: eh it's even simplier
if ( v == (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1) ) { ... }
called in onCreateContextMenu

Comment: @kamilosdjikos that won't work, v == (some view) isn't true. he could do v.equals((some view)); but running equals is less efficient. switch(v.getId() case R.id.("view_id"): would be the way to go, but i was just trying to let him know v.getId() got the id for him.